# Regex - set max limit containing any char and numbers

Tags: java, regex, phone-number

I want to match strings with the following formats

- 00355901234567
- +355901234567
- +*#355901234567
- +355*#90123456
- 44*#abc#9112345

and not match:

- 0035590123456789
- 44*#abc#91123456789
- 44*#abc#911234567Abc

I just want to match any character in the beginning of the string and numbers in the end. the whole string should not exceed 15 characters.

So far, I've reached this regex:

```
^(.*)?\d{0,15}$
```

Although, the limit isn't working when I match any character with `(.*)`.

Any thoughts?

Comment: `.*` is *greedy*, meaning it will match as many characters as possible. You can make it lazy by adding a `?`, like so: `(.*?)...`.

Comment: did you want to match `+355*#90123456#` ? It's unclear for me. Could you explain your question a bit more?

Comment: @AvinashRaj no sry, edited!

Comment: Why you don't want to match this `+355*#90123456#`? it has zero digit at the last.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like

```
^.{0,14}\d$
```

see the example : http://regex101.com/r/mK4dR9/3